# How to add host into the ambari-server cluster?

Tags: curl, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to add host using the below curl command.

```
curl --user admin:passwd -i -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X POST http://182.29.6.3:8080/api/v1/clusters/prod/hosts/ip-182-29-6-3.us-east-2.ec2.internal
```

But, I am getting below bad requets

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request X-Frame-Options: DENY X-XSS-Protection: 1;
>   mode=block Set-Cookie:
>   AMBARISESSIONID=d52ibb6a8b6q1tmqm2l21q85e;Path=/;HttpOnly Expires:
>   Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT User: admin Content-Type: text/plain
>   Content-Length: 179 Server: Jetty(8.1.19.v20160209)
>
> {   "status" : 400,   "message" : "Attempted to add unknown hosts to a
>   cluster.  These hosts have not been registered with the server:
>   ip-182-29-6-3.us-east-2.ec2.internal"

Answer (score 0):

This command helps you to add a host to the hdp cluster through ambari REST API, adds YARN Node manager service, deploys configuration and start service on the node.

```
#!/bin/bash
# variables
HOSTNAME=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname)
hostname $HOSTNAME
USERNAME='username'
PASSWORD='password'
CLUSTER_NAME='mycluster'
AMBARI_HOST='ip-172-166-11-52.ap-south-1.compute.internal'
AMBARI_PORT='8080'

#start ambari agent if its not running on the host to be registered and wait for 30 seconds for the agent to become up and running
/etc/init.d/ambari-agent start
sleep 30

# add a host to the cluster
curl --user $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -i -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X POST http://$AMBARI_HOST:$AMBARI_PORT/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTER_NAME/hosts/$HOSTNAME
sleep 30

#add node manager service to the node
curl --user $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -i -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X POST http://$AMBARI_HOST:$AMBARI_PORT/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTER_NAME/hosts/$HOSTNAME/host_components/NODEMANAGER
sleep 30

#install node manager packages and deploy configs it is not already present in the node
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -i -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X PUT -d '{"RequestInfo":{"context":"Install"},"Body":{"HostRoles":{"state":"INSTALLED"}}}' http://$AMBARI_HOST:$AMBARI_PORT/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTER_NAME/hosts/$HOSTNAME/host_components/NODEMANAGER
sleep 30

# start node manager service
curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -i -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X PUT -d '{"HostRoles": {"state": "STARTED"}}' http://$AMBARI_HOST:$AMBARI_PORT/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTER_NAME/hosts/$HOSTNAME/host_components/NODEMANAGER
```